# Not getting all notification when device connect with Internet connection

Tags: ios, swift, socket.io, apple-push-notifications

I am developing chat app with `socket.io`, chat is working fine when both device are connected with socket and Internet. Problem arise when two persons are doing chat with each other, Lets say `A` and `B` doing chat with each other and its working fine with Internet connection, but If user `A` make off his internet. And User `B` send text message 1,2,3,4,5 and 6. Then after few second or few minutes if User `A` connect with Internet Then User `A` gets only one notification of the one message from above six.

And I also check from socket server, and server send all push notification to APNS but APNS sends only one push notification.

And some times I get all 6 messages in push notification, so I can’t understand what is the problem?

Can any one help me why push notification is missing from APNS?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

From our end all we can do is send the payload to APNS, and APNS will be sending those notification to the device. We cannot rely on the notification as it may arrive at the correct moment or it may not arrive at all.
Relying on notifications can be a doubled edged sword at times.

But [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376-CH1-TNTAG23) is a nice document by apple, as to why this might happen in your case.

Comment: I think your link is right but I also check whatsapp application, I think they are managing with VoIP.

Comment: @SAMIRRATHOD That true. they are using VoIP. even I am using it in one of my app.but after iOS13, apple restricted to use PushKit notification for VoIP purpose only.